# I can see the files between two dates but I need to copy and merge them to another folder too

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

In a directory I can display the files(parquet) between two dates using below codes but I need to copy and merge them to another folder too where there is already a file residing in JSON format. How do I do that.

```
for(dirpath,dirnames,filenames) in os.walk(path):
      for filesname in filenames:
        f = '/'.join([dirpath,filesname])
        ctime = os.stat(f)[-1]
        if ctime>d1 and ctime <=d2:
          print(f)
```

Comment: Which type of files are there that you want to merge ?

Comment: @DeepakTripathi I have Parquet files in source and in target I have to change format and save as JSON.

Answer (score 0):

just read parquet and write to json ?

```
spark.read.parquet("path/to/file.parquet").write.json("path/to/file.json")
```